# Is RabbitMQ capable of "pushing" messages from a queue to a consumer?

Tags: queue, rabbitmq

With RabbitMQ, is there a way to "push" messages from a queue TO a consumer as opposed to having a consumer "poll and pull" messages FROM a queue?

This has been the cause of some debate on a current project i'm on. The argument from one side is that having consumers (i.e. a windows service) "poll" a queue until a new message arrives is somewhat inefficient and less desirable than the idea having the message "pushed" automatically from the queue to the subscriber(s)/consumer(s).

I can only seem to find information supporting the idea of consumers "polling and pulling" messages off of a queue (e.g. using a windows service to poll the queue for new messages). There isn't much information on the idea of "pushing" messages to a consumer/subscriber...

Comment: You could certainly have an out-of-band mechanism to notify consumers to start looking for stuff in the queue, but why even have a queue if your tasks are so infrequent that you're worried about the efficiency of _idling_?

Comment: @U2EF1 But even then, the out-of-band mechanism to notify consumers has to use some type of "polling" to watch for new messages, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, probably `select` or `kqueue` at the lowest level. So, you guys should probably not worry about it and build your thing. I'm 95% sure that polling rabbitmq is not going to be the bottleneck in your system.

Comment: In AMQP `basic.consume` works exactly as you asked - consumer subscribes to receive messages from specific queue and then broker notifies consumer with messages from that queue, from head to tail (FIFO). And why having consumers are inefficient?

Comment: I have the following issues with the kafka polling consumers:
1. The number of consumers is bound to the number of queue partitions. If you want to increase your consumer PODs you have to manually increase the queue partitions.

2. Polling consumers in kubernetes don't have an API, which means they are not called by someone and hence kubernetes cannot scale them automatically. In other words polling consumers can't be scaled by the clound/kubernetes like any REST service

3. Trying to consume messages in a batch in the consumer requires multithreading, which is OK. But again why should...

Comment: ... multithread a consumer myself when this is automatically done in any REST service.

I prefer RabbitMQ over kafka because the the Rabbit consumers can by called! this makes automatic use of REST/http service load balancing in the clould

Answer (score 11):

Having the server *push* messages to the client is one of the two ways to get messages to the client, and the preferred way for most applications.  This is known as *consuming* messages via a *subscription*.

The client is connected.  (The AMQP/RabbitMQ/most messaging systems model is that the client is *always* connected - except for network interruptions, of course.)

You use the client API to arrange that your channel consume messages by supplying a callback method. Then whenever a message is available the server sends it to the client over the channel and the client application gets it via an asynchronous callback (typically one thread per channel).  You can set the "prefetch count" on the channel which controls the amount of pipelining your client can do over that channel.  (For further parallelism an application can have multiple channels running over one connection, which is a common design that serves various purposes.)

The alternative is for the client to *poll* for messages one at a time, over the channel, via a *get* method.

Answer (score 3):

You "push" messages from Producer to Exchange.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html

BTW this is fitting very well IoT scenarios. Devices produce messages and sends them to an exchange. Queue is handling persistence, FIFO and other features, as well as delivery of messages to subscribers.

And, by the way, you never "Poll" the queue. Instead, you always subscribe to publisher. Similar to observer pattern. Generally, I would say genius principle.
So it is similar to post box or post office, except it sends you a notification when message is available.

Comment: This makes the most sense to me. "You get a notification pushed that a message is available" not the message itself pushed. Cheers.

Comment: No, you actually get the message.   I think the answer meant to say you don't poll for it - the RabbitMQ framework gives you a callback (that's the "notification") but the callback has the message.

Comment: Shouldn't that depend on the use-case? Whether the entire message needs to be pulled after it's become available.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the docs [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#amqp-model):

> AMQP brokers either deliver messages to consumers subscribed to
>   queues, or consumers fetch/pull messages from queues on demand.

And from [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#consumers):

> Storing messages in queues is useless unless applications can consume
>   them. In the AMQP 0-9-1 Model, there are two ways for applications to
>   do this:
>
> ```
> Have messages delivered to them ("push API")
> Fetch messages as needed ("pull API")
> ```
>
> With the "push API", applications have to indicate interest in
>   consuming messages from a particular queue. When they do so, we say
>   that they register a consumer or, simply put, subscribe to a queue. It
>   is possible to have more than one consumer per queue or to register an
>   exclusive consumer (excludes all other consumers from the queue while
>   it is consuming).
>
> Each consumer (subscription) has an identifier called a consumer tag.
>   It can be used to unsubscribe from messages. Consumer tags are just
>   strings.

Answer (score -2):

RabbitMQ broker is like server that wont send data to consumer without consumer client getting registering itself to server. but then question comes like below

Can RabbitMQ keep client consumer details and connect to client when packet comes?

Answer is no. so what is alternative well then write plugin by yourself that maintain client information in some kind of config. Plugin will pull from RabbitMQ Queue and push to client.

Please give look at this plugin might help.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html

Frankly speaking Client need to implement AMQP protocol to receive so and should listen connection on some port for that. This sound like another server.

Regards,
Vishal

Comment: I'm not completely convinced you understand the proper use cases for RabbitMQ

Comment: I don't understand the negative votes: this is exactly what I was looking for, a way to have peripheral rabbitmqs forwarding messages to a central collector, be it another rabbitmq or my own destination service.